# How to use a c++ library in swift project to make a better glsl compiler

Tags: c++, swift, xcode

I am trying to use [this glsl optimizer](https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer) in my swift project. I dont know if this is possible.

I really dont know what I am doing, however my guess was to drag "libglsl_optimizer.a" in my project.

Then I created a bridging header, and put in `#import "libglsl_optimizer.a"`

However that meerly causes the build to freeze.

How can i get this library to work? Am I going about this the right way?

I got the .a file by going through the download zip. In projects/xcode5/glsl_optimizer_lib.xcproj. Then I built it and then grabbed the result in the products folder. I dragged that into the project.

EDIT:
Ok interesting thing I tried compiling without the bridging header and I noticed this warning

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/MB/Desktop/XCode/Projects/ArrayParticles/Trillium/ArrayCreation/libglsl_optimizer.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/MB/Desktop/XCode/Projects/ArrayParticles/Trillium/ArrayCreation/libglsl_optimizer.a
```

Comment: Where did you get the `.a` file? (The real concern is whether it matches the target architecture.) Can you share the build log?

Comment: @szym I added it to the question

Comment: @szym I noticed you were right about the architecture. How do I change the .a files architecture?

Comment: I posted an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the architecture of the library matches your target architecture (iOS device or simulator).

To change the architecture in the `glsl_optimizer_lib.xcproj` (which targets x86 MacOS by default), open the target settings and change `Base SDK` to iOS. This will automatically select the standard arm* architectures:

[image]

Then to switch between simulator and device ("Generic iOS Device"), select it from the scheme selector (it defaults to simulator):

[image]

If you want to create one library that works with both iOS devices and simulator, you will need to build a multi-architecture framework.

Comment: OK I did that, no more build warning. I even built it with the target being the ipod. Unfortunately when I try to build with it in the bridging header it gets stuck.

Comment: Does it freeze? Can you post the build log step it ends on?

Comment: unfortunately I am looking at a progress bar when it freezes

Comment: Does Xcode stop responding at that point? Logs are available in the last tab in the Navigator (left pane). There should be a "Build" log there.

Comment: No it still responds. It stops when compiling a source file Devices.swift. It has nothing to do with this library and usually compiles fine, so Im suspecting the pause is whatever comes after it. The file is a slightly modified version of device kit (https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit) it has some odd import statements